# Android google cast- I am unable to set image thumbnail on notification and lock screen as per current casting Video

Tags: java, android, google-chrome

I am just trying to show thumbnail image which is currently playing on chrome cast through my android sender application. Its showing on Lock full screen but now showing on notification bar image and lock screen notification image,Currently is title is getting update as per the currnet video playing on chrome-cast, but image is not loading.

It would be great if anyone resolve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

[image][image]
My android code are below:

```
  if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

                                videoMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse("https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/images/480x270/DesigningForGoogleCast2-480x270.jpg")));
                                videoMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse("https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/images/780x1200/DesigningForGoogleCast-887x1200.jpg")));
                            }
                            MediaInfo mediaInfo = null;

                            if (videoMetadata != null) {
                                mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(videoUrl)
                                        .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                                        .setContentType("videos/mp4")
                                        .setMetadata(videoMetadata)
                                        .build();
                                arlMediaItem.add(new MediaQueueItem.Builder(mediaInfo).build());


                            }

            resultPendingResult = getRemoteMediaClient().queueLoad(getArrayFromList(arlMediaItem)
                    , starPos, MediaStatus.REPEAT_MODE_REPEAT_OFF, null);
            if (resultPendingResult != null)
                resultPendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull RemoteMediaClient.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {
                        switch (mediaChannelResult.getStatus().getStatusCode()) {
                            case RemoteMediaClient.STATUS_FAILED:
                                break;
                            case RemoteMediaClient.RESUME_STATE_PAUSE:
                                break;
                            case RemoteMediaClient.RESUME_STATE_PLAY:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

CastOptionsProvider

---

```
public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {
    static  String  TAG = CastOptionsProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {

        NotificationOptions notificationOptions = new NotificationOptions.Builder()
                .setActions(Arrays.asList(
                        MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK,
                        MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_STOP_CASTING), new int[]{0,1})
                .setTargetActivityClassName(AdvancedVideoPlayerActivity.class.getName())
                .build();
        CastMediaOptions mediaOptions = new CastMediaOptions.Builder()
                .setImagePicker(new ImagePickerImpl())
                .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
                .setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(AdvancedVideoPlayerActivity.class.getName())
                .build();

        return new CastOptions.Builder()
                .setReceiverApplicationId(CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID)
                .setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
                .build();




    }
    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
        return null;
    }


    private static class ImagePickerImpl extends ImagePicker {

        @Override
        public WebImage onPickImage(MediaMetadata mediaMetadata, ImageHints imageHints) {
            if ((mediaMetadata == null) || !mediaMetadata.hasImages()) {
                return null;
            }
            List<WebImage> images = mediaMetadata.getImages();
            if (images.size() == 1) {
                return images.get(0);
            } else {
                if (imageHints.getType() == ImagePicker.IMAGE_TYPE_MEDIA_ROUTE_CONTROLLER_DIALOG_BACKGROUND) {

                    return images.get(0);
                } else {
                    return images.get(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ankit! I have the same issue right now. I tried returning a known hardcoded image with no luck. Please, let me know if you solve it! I'll do the same.

Comment: Ankit! I just resolved it updating dependencies to latest versions. Give a try if you like!

Comment: Hi malvarez, Thanks for your reply, Could you please let me know which dependency version you are using for now ?

Comment: I'm using https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer and its extension exoplayer-cast. I passed from 2.8.1 to 2.9.0 and it solved my problem. Sadly, it has a bug in cast dialog (borders too wide)